# Crop BMP file image in c program

Tags: c, gcc, image-processing, visual-studio-code, malloc

My function is getting an Image and I am trying to crop the BMP image 
by size: 100 x 100, 200 x 200, 300 x 300, 400 x 400 by Pixels , 
i don't know what to do make it work.  please help me

The size of the image is int height and int width and the function knows the values in pixels.

Here is my code:

```
void re_allocate_pixels(struct RGB_Image *image, int new_height, int new_width)
{
    int org_height = image->height;
    int org_width = image->width;
    int org_size = image->size;
    int i;
    struct Pixel **pxls;
    pxls = (struct Pixel **)malloc((org_height) * sizeof(struct Pixel *));
    if (pxls == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < org_height; i++)
    {
        pxls[i] = (struct Pixel *)malloc(org_width * sizeof(struct Pixel));
        if (pxls[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
     //i have no idea what to do next to crop the image and pixecl 
    /*for (int j = 0; j < org_height; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < org_width; k++)
        {
            pxls[i][j] = pxls[k][j];
        }
    }*/
}
```

here are struct data:

```
    struct Pixel
    {
        unsigned char red;
        unsigned char green;
        unsigned char blue;
    };
    struct RGB_Image
    {
        char file_name[MAX_FILE_NAME_SIZE];
        long height;
        long width;
        long size;
        struct Pixel **pixels;
    };
```

here is how am calling this function

```
struct RGB_Image *rgb_img_ptr;
struct RGB_Image image;
rgb_img_ptr = &image;
int image_load_ret_value = load_image(rgb_img_ptr);
re_allocate_pixels(rgb_img_ptr, 100,100); // here is calling
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us in which way the function does not work. What do you expect, what do you get instead? What data do you feed into the function?

Comment: You will also need the row length, which might be more than `sizeof(struct Pixel) * width`, because the number of bytes in each row must be divisible by 4.

Comment: Since this is a homework assignment (I saw a similar question a few days ago) post the exact instructions so that everybody knows the restrictions.

Comment: Why are you allocating memory for `org_height` and `org_width` and not `new_height` and `new_width`?

Comment: @Gerhardh  : it's not cropping the image just give me the cruppt image ,
i need help from sombody who can solve and add aditional code

Comment: @WeatherVane : oh here i did mistake .

Comment: Copy the pixel data with nested column and row loops, or a row loop with `memcpy`. The destination indexes will be different from the source, unless the crop is at (0,0).

Comment: Please add all important information to the question (use the edit button). Comments might be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the old allocation and also assign the new `size` value. `size` usually refers to "width in bytes" multiplied by height.

In this case the value for "width in bytes" should be "width * 3", and it should always be a multiple of 4.

Read the image one row at a time. Use `mempcy` to copy each row.

Note that bitmaps are usually upside down. You may have to change the loop to `for (int y = dst.height - 1; y >=0; y--){memcpy...}`

```
void re_allocate_pixels(struct RGB_Image *image, int new_height, int new_width)
{
    if(new_width > image->width) return;
    if(new_height > image->height) return;

    struct RGB_Image *src = image;
    struct RGB_Image dst;

    dst.width = new_width;
    dst.height = new_height;

    //allocate memory
    dst.pixels = malloc(dst.height * sizeof(struct Pixel*));
    for(int y = 0; y < dst.height; y++)
        dst.pixels[y] = malloc(dst.width * sizeof(struct Pixel));

    //copy from source to destination
    for(int y = 0; y < dst.height; y++)
        memcpy(dst.pixels[y], src->pixels[y], dst.width * sizeof(struct Pixel));

    //free the old allocation
    for(int y = 0; y < src->height; y++)
        free(image->pixels[y]);
    free(image->pixels);

    //assing new allocation
    image->pixels = dst.pixels;

    //set the new width, height, size
    image->width = dst.width;
    image->height = dst.height;

    int bitcount = 24;
    int bytecount = 3; //<- same as sizeof(struct Pixel)

    //calculate width in bytes
    int width_in_bytes = ((dst.width * bitcount + 31) / 32) * 4;

    image->size = width_in_bytes * dst.height;
}
```